# matplotlib 3D scatterplot with marker color corresponding to RGB values

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have loaded a picture into a numpy array using mahotas.

```
import mahotas
img = mahotas.imread('test.jpg')
```

Each pixel in `img` is represented by an array of RGB values:

```
img[1,1] = [254, 200, 189]
```

I have made a 3D scatterplot of R values on one axis, G values on the 2nd axis and B values on the third axis. This is no problem:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
for i in range(1,img.shape[1]+1):
    xs = img[i,1][0]
    ys = img[i,1][1]
    zs = img[i,1][2]
    ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, c='0.5', marker='o')
ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
```

(I'm just plotting the first column of the image for the time being).

How can I color each of the scatterplot dots by the color of each image pixel? i.e. I guess I would like to color the dots by their RGB value, but I'm not sure if this is possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, but it needs to be done through a separate mechanism than the `c` argument.  In a nutshell, use `facecolors=rgb_array`.

---

First off, let me explain what's going on. The `Collection` that `scatter` returns has two "systems" (for lack of a better term) for setting colors.

If you use the `c` argument, you're setting the colors through the `ScalarMappable` "system".  This specifies that the colors should be controlled by applying a colormap to a single variable.  (This is the `set_array` method of anything that inherits from `ScalarMappable`.)

In addition to the `ScalarMappable` system, the colors of a collection can be set independently.  In that case, you'd use the `facecolors` kwarg.

---

As a quick example, these points will have randomly specified rgb colors:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x, y = np.random.random((2, 10))
rgb = np.random.random((10, 3))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y, s=200, facecolors=rgb)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: and how would it apply in my case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52788407/how-to-plot-graphics-with-the-colors-of-each-pixel-in-the-image