# Matplotlib pcolormesh using RGB tuples

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399248/matplotlib-3d-scatterplot-with-marker-color-corresponding-to-rgb-values) illustrates how scatterplot marker colors can be specified by RGB tuples.

Is it possible to something similar for color meshes, where the color of each x,y pair is given by an RGB tuple rather than as a colormap value?

Comment: Do you mean with `pcolor` or with `pcolormesh`? Just from analogy with the scatterplot, would the `edgecolors` keyword work?

Comment: imshow may be what's necessary

Comment: ***rgb = np.random.random((10, 3))*** is colour definition

Comment: `imshow` did do the trick.

Comment: I have a vague memory that applying pre-existing RGBA values (rather than scalars that mpl color maps for you) is an open issue on github as a feature request.

Comment: Can you please write up how you used imshow to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if `pcolormesh` can be easily used to create an rgb image (and I'm interested in the answer to that question myself). However, it is relatively easy to create an rgb image with `imshow` or `axes_grid1.axes_rgb`. Summarizing more comprehensive tutorials [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/03/display-matplotlib-rgb-image/) and [here](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html#rgb-axes):

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.axes_rgb import RGBAxes

rgb = np.random.random((5, 5, 3))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = RGBAxes(fig, [0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
ax.imshow_rgb(rgb[:,:,0],rgb[:,:,1],rgb[:,:,2],interpolation='none')

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(rgb,interpolation='none')
```

The resulting images are shown below:

[image: axes_rgb]
[image: imshow_rgb]