# Scatterplot wherein each point color is a different mixture of K colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, colors, scatter-plot

I have 2D data that I want to cluster into K clusters. Lets suppose `K=4`. After running the clustering algorithm, each point has a 4 length probability vector (whose entries add up to one) indicating the probability that the point belongs to each one of the clusters.

My idea is to assign a color to each cluster and after that make a scatter plot wherein each point is colored as a mixture of all the colors according to its probability vector. If `K=3` it the colors could be RGB and therefore I could make use of something like `ax.scatter(x1, x2, facecolors=probability_vectors)` like its said in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399248/matplotlib-3d-scatterplot-with-marker-color-corresponding-to-rgb-values) . I used that solution to make the plot in the image which has `K=2` (fixing the Blue column to 0 in all vectors). I could still use it for `K=3` but for `K=4` I need something different. Any suggestion?
[image: 2D scatter plot with probabilites]

## **EDIT:**

Using [Tomáš Šíma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1283853/tom%C3%A1%C5%A1-%C5%A0%C3%ADma) answer, if I use this code (for 5 clusters):

```
import colorsys
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 5
HSV = [(float(x)/N, 1, 1) for x in range(1,N+1)]
RGB = map(lambda x: colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(*x), HSV)

print HSV
plt.scatter(range(N),np.repeat(0.5,N),c=RGB,s=200)
```

I get this output:

`[(0.2, 1, 1), (0.4, 1, 1), (0.6, 1, 1), (0.8, 1, 1), (1.0, 1, 1)]`
[image]

My problem now is that if I had one point whose probability vector is `[0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5]`, i.e. one half for the yellow cluster and one half for the red one, its color should be orange. However, if I do `0.5*0.2 + 0.5*1.0` I get `0.6` which is blue. How should I compute the average in order to get orange instead of blue?

## **EDIT 2:**

Got it, I just have to average the RGB version of each cluster centroid (instead of the HUE)

:D
[image]

Comment: You were right about mixing the colors, so I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for HSB colorspace.

Color in HSB is made of 3 values:

- H =  HUE - actual color
- S = Saturation - how much color is there(the    less, the more the
  color look like grayscale)
- B = Brightness

You can generate N most distinct colors from this space easily and then convert to RGB

```
import colorsys
N = 5
HSV = [(x*1.0/N, 0.5, 0.5) for x in range(N)]
RGB = map(lambda x: colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(*x), HSV)
```

For mixing the HSB color for painting the points, you can do weight average for the corresponding RGB colors with weight equal to the probability vector.

Comment: Ok so with that I have the color in RGB format for each point (great), which I can to pass as the `color` paramater of `plt.plot()` if were to plot the scatter manually point by point (iterating over the dataset and the computed color matrix). But how can I use your solution with the `plt.scatter()` method?

Comment: Ok I just have to pass the RGB matrix as the `c` parameter of `plt.scatter()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RGBA scheme as mentioned in the [Colormap section](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html) of matplotlib colors documentation. The A stands for alpha. Also read the [ScalarMappable section](http://matplotlib.org/api/cm_api.html#matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable).

Modifying from the answer quoted in the question:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x, y = np.random.random((2, 10))
rgba = np.random.random((10, 4))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y, s=200, facecolors=rgba)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Nice. However, your solution does not scale for `K>4`, right?